# How to display text as a texture in Android OpenGL ES 1.1?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am a developer in Korea.

English not good. Please note the benefits.

I would want to find an example of how to display the text using the texture of OpenGL ES for Android.

I did look at the reference material on the Internet, but most intermediate process is omitted or, methodology has been described.

We would like to try to learn to imitate to see the code written in full and sample a little harder to see me immature is still merit.

We also recommend a example very simple. Driving try once, I want to see to understand by looking at the code.

Have a good day~.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [Rajawali library](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/).. It has very good examples of displaying text using texture..

Comment: Thank's for your answer Sanket!!  However, the text texture of this site, where is it?

Comment: Check its sample project..Link to download sample is - https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliExamples and library is - https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please accept it as a answer.. so others can take benefit of this question and answer.. thanks...

Comment: Sanket. We apologize that the answer was delayed. But I do not know what class is the class text. Sorry for the painful question. However, I do not know really.

Comment: @Scanket, could you give which texture class we can use to display text with rajawali lib? And I can't find text sample from the rajawali examples? :(